# Trying to do calculation code for a calculator in android application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, calculator

I am trying to sort a calculator app out in android. I have the layout set out fine and now I just need to do the code that will calculate. The app needs to show the number when it is pressed, then if say the + button is pressed it will store the first number, clear it off the screen, get a second number and then add them together. When the equal button is pressed it needs to show the results.

So far I have

```
public class Calculator extends Activity {

    public EditText display;  
    TextView screen;
    int a, result;
    int c;
    Button b1;
    int sum1, sum2;
    String r;

    public int getSum1(int sum1) {
        return sum1;
    }

    public int getSum2(int sum2) {
        return sum2;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);  

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void buttonEventHandler(View v) {
        screen=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.screen);
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        switch(v.getId()) {

        case R.id.button1 :
            screen.setText(screen.getText() + "1");
            c = +1;
            break;

        case R.id.button2 : 
            screen.setText(screen.getText() + "2");
            c = +2;
            break;

        case R.id.button3 : 
            screen.setText(screen.getText() + "3");
            c = +3;
            break;

        case R.id.button4 : 
            screen.setText(screen.getText() + "4");
            c = +4;
            break;

        case R.id.button5 : 
            screen.setText(screen.getText() + "5");
            c = +5;
            break;

        case R.id.button6 : 
            screen.setText(screen.getText() + "6");
            c = +6;
            break;

        case R.id.button7 : 
            screen.setText(screen.getText() + "7");
            c = +7;
            break;

        case R.id.button8 : 
            screen.setText(screen.getText() + "8");
            c = +8;
            break;

        case R.id.button9 : 
            screen.setText(screen.getText() + "9");
            c = +9;
            break;

        case R.id.button0 : 
            screen.setText(screen.getText() + "0");
            c = +0;
            break;

        case R.id.buttonC :
            screen.setText(screen.getText() + "");
            c = 0;
            break;

        case R.id.buttonPlus :          


        case R.id.buttonEquals :



        }


    }
}
```

How to do calculations?

Comment: Are you looking for `Integer.parseInt(screen.getText())`?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your `sum1` to zero in `onCreate`. When the user taps `+`, do:

1. Add `c` to `sum1`
2. Display `sum1`
3. Reset `c` to zero so a new number can be typed

When the user taps `=`, do:

1. Add `c` to `sum1`
2. Display `sum1`
3. Reset `c` and `sum1` to zero

This allows you to tap `4 + 5 + 6 =` and see `15`, for example.

Comment: thank you.

Would my code for this be

     case R.id.buttonPlus :     
      sum1 = +c;
      screen.setText(sum1);
      c = 0;

      
     case R.id.buttonEquals :
      sum1 = +c;
      screen.setText(sum1);
      c = 0;

Comment: Instead of `= +`, I'd recommend `+=`. R.id.buttonEquals should also do `sum1 = 0`. Also, when you tap the digits 0 through 9, the code should say something like `c = c * 10 + 4`; otherwise, when you tap 9, then 4, you'll get 13 rather than the 94 you expect.

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly loaded question. It can get more complex as you go depending on how many calculations you want to do. Will it be limited to `x + y`? Or are you looking to allow things like `3 * (4 + 5) / 6 + 3`?

The latter will complicate things much further probably requiring you to implement a `tree` datatype in some form or another. Here's a discussion that I found on google: http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/algorithms-recursion/605-java-calculator.html

If you're going for the former, you need to allow `+` to store the current value of `c` into a datatype, then clear the screen and reset `c` to 0. Once `=` is pressed it will evaluate the sum and report it back to the screen. Be sure to include any checks to make sure no values are null.

More details about your intentions and plans might be of use to help myself and others understand the scope of your project.

Comment: All I need it to do is simple calculations just as a+y, thank you for your help